mgcv::gam predictions with observation-level / residual variance?
Is there a way to include residual variance in the predictions from predict.gam()?
For reference: I've used brms for similar purposes before, and it has two distinct functions, fitted() and predict(). The difference, as explained [here][1], is that of three sources of uncertainty:

the residual (observation-level) variance
the uncertainty in the fixed coefficients
the uncertainty in the variance parameters for the grouping factors

fitted() includes (2) and (3) whereas predict() includes all three. In effect, fitted() gives predictions and credible intervals for the expected value, whereas predict() gives them for the observed value. The main predicted values are the equivalent but the intervals are, unsurprisingly, wider for predict().
As far as I can tell, predict.gam() with se.fit=TRUE gives the equivalent of brms::fitted(), i.e. its estimated error is for the expected value, and hence results in a much narrower prediction interval. Is there some way to incorporate the observation-level residual variance in the predicted errors?

You can do this with a GAM fitted in mgcv but it requires additional work to do the posterior sampling that brms (Stan) has already done to fit the model.
What you mean by a predicted value and credible interval for the observed value implies simulating from the model new values of the response that includes the uncertainty in the estimated coefficients, and the sampling uncertainty that arises as viewing an observation as a draw from it's conditional distribution given the model.
As it happens, I just released version 0.9.0 of my gratia package which will do this for you for a GAM fitted with mgcv. I have an in-progress vignette describing the different kinds of posterior sampling you can do with gratia: https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/articles/posterior-simulation.html
Assuming I have understood what you want correctly, you can use gratia::posterior_samples() to generate the values and interval you want.
Here is the example of creating prediction intervals for a model with a single smooth (the approach works just fine for multiple smooth models too, it's just easier to visualise things with a single predictor):
stopifnot(packageVersion("gratia") >= "0.9.0")
# if this errors, run install.packages("gratia")
# although you might need a reasonably new R to run it

library("gratia")

# generate some data from a model with a single smooth effect with draws
# from a Gaussian
df <- data_sim("gwf2", n = 400, scale = 1, dist = "normal", seed = 8)

# fit a GAM to these data
m <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = df, method = "REML", family = gaussian())

# create new data evenly over `x` at which we will predict
ds <- data_slice(m, x = evenly(x, n = 200)) |>
  mutate(.row = row_number())

# now do the posterior sampling
# the unconditional = TRUE bit uses the smoothing parameter-corrected
# version of the Bayesian covariance matrix of the model coefficients
# it's a way to (try to) correct for treating the smoothing parameters as
# known, when in fact we didn't know them at all and instead selected them
# from the data
ps <- posterior_samples(m, n = 10000, data = ds, seed = 24,
  unconditional = TRUE) |>
  left_join(ds, by = join_by(.row == .row)) # join with prediction data

# write a function to summarise the posterior
quantile_fun <- function(x, probs = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975), ...) {
  tibble::tibble(
    .value = quantile(x, probs = probs, ...),
    .q = probs * 100
  )
}

# summarise the posterior retaining median and 95% Bayesian credible 
# interval
p_int <- ps |>
  group_by(.row) |>
  reframe(quantile_fun(.response)) |>
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = .row, names_from = .q, values_from = .value,
    names_prefix = ".q"
  ) |>
  left_join(ds, by = join_by(.row == .row))

If we visualise the posterior (using code from the vignette) plus a couple of other things produced in the vignette but not shown above, we have:

Where the filled hexagons shown the number of posterior draws in that bin as a way to show the posterior samples themselves, while the outermost light blue lines show the 95% Bayesian prediction interval. The innermost blue lines are what you'd get from predict.gam() with se = TRUE and formed the usual 95% confidence interval (which in the case of a GAM with penalized splines etc is a Bayesian credible interval).
If you don't want to assume the posterior distribution can be well-approximated using a Gaussian, then we also have access to a simple Metropolis Hastings sampler via mgcv::gam.mh(). This sampler alternates random walk proposals with t proposals (although the default settings use a large number for the degrees of freedom so it is essentially a Gaussian), and works much better when the posterior isn't well-approximated by a Gaussian.
To use this in posterior_samples(), change the method argument and set some values for the sampler (burnin, t_df, etc):
posterior_samples(m, n = 10000, data = ds, seed = 24,
  unconditional = TRUE,
  method = "mh", # use the Metropolis Hastings sampler
  thin = 2,      # taking every other draw
  rw_scale = 0.4 # shrink the Bayesian VCOV by this in RW proposals
) |> 
  left_join(ds, by = join_by(.row == .row)) # join with prediction data

